# OOP PHP user class (usercake) not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, usercake

I recently found this little user class script called usercake (http://usercake.com/), has all the basic functionality and seems to work very well.

**My problem**:  The first user gets added to the database fine, but after that it is not working.  Clearly there's just something slightly wrong that I'm not figuring out ( i do not know oop php very well).  No errors occure (that i can see), and the email gets sent out.

I've installed it multiple places with the same fate.  I'd like to fix it because using this script saves a lot of reinventing the wheel time.

Here is the URL where I have it: http://rawcomposition.com/birding/loggedin/register.php
Here is the function that gets called once everything is validated:

```
    public function userCakeAddUser()
{
    global $db,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix;

    //Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
    if($this->status)
    {
        //Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
        $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);

        //Construct a unique activation token
        $this->activation_token = generateActivationToken();

        //Do we need to send out an activation email?
        if($emailActivation)
        {
            //User must activate their account first
            $this->user_active = 0;

            $mail = new userCakeMail();

            //Build the activation message
            $activation_message = lang("ACTIVATION_MESSAGE",array($websiteUrl,$this->activation_token));

            //Define more if you want to build larger structures
            $hooks = array(
                "searchStrs" => array("#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE","#ACTIVATION-KEY","#USERNAME#"),
                "subjectStrs" => array($activation_message,$this->activation_token,$this->unclean_username)
            );

            /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function 
            Instead to pass a message. */
            if(!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt",$hooks))
            {
                $this->mail_failure = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject. 
                //SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.

                if(!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email,"New User"))
                {
                    $this->mail_failure = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Instant account activation
            $this->user_active = 1;
        }   


        if(!$this->mail_failure)
        {
                //Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$db_table_prefix."Users` (
                        `Username`,
                        `Username_Clean`,
                        `Password`,
                        `Email`,
                        `ActivationToken`,
                        `LastActivationRequest`,
                        `LostPasswordRequest`, 
                        `Active`,
                        `Group_ID`,
                        `SignUpDate`,
                        `LastSignIn`
                        )
                        VALUES (
                        '".$db->sql_escape($this->unclean_username)."',
                        '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_username)."',
                        '".$secure_pass."',
                        '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_email)."',
                        '".$this->activation_token."',
                        '".time()."',
                        '0',
                        '".$this->user_active."',
                        '1',
                        '".time()."',
                        '0'
                        )";

            return $db->sql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userCake_Users` (
  `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Username_Clean` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ActivationToken` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `LastActivationRequest` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LostPasswordRequest` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Group_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SignUpDate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastSignIn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: missed a auto_increment on the PK ?

Comment: what a bad code, starting by globals and not using pdo

Comment: Auto increment is present in the DB structure.  @yes123:  do you know of a better PHP user class to use that doesn't require hours and hours of time making it work?

Comment: Check db connection details in models/settings.php, especially db host. Also try add ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL); at the beginning of your script, maybe you will see some errors/warnings.

Comment: Settings are correct, and i tried putting the display all errors code on the registration page, with no luck..  It adds the very first user, but after that, nothing gets added..

Comment: @Adam, I'm not sure if you are still looking for responses here, but feel free to check my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To me, there are 2 possibilities why it is not adding further users after the first one is added:

First, `$this->mail_failure` flag is set to TRUE for the following user accounts after the first user is created. But this scenario is not likely because it is the same code that has run successfully for the first user and therefore there is no reason why the flag should be TRUE for others.

Second possibility is that `$this->status` is FALSE for the second user account. If false, the method `userCakeAddUser()` does not do anything. The reasons why this flag could be false is either the username or the email address already exists.

Are you using the same username or email address you used for the first account for the second account as well? I'm sure you must not be using the same username but perhaps the same email address. The usercake classes does not allow the same username or same email addresses.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would do 4 things with this uggly code :

1) to enable the error_reporting mode so that you can see something in case sthg occurs :

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

2) to test this INSERT sql **straight into the dB** to make sure it's working properly, and validate this piece of code. If the sql INSERT request is valid, then check the access conditions to these SQL request, like Abhay said above,

3) As we do not have your all config available, a guess game is difficult. So I'd suggest you to add one NULL field for the AI User_ID.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$db_table_prefix."Users` (
                    `User_ID`, // Add this here
                    `Username`,
                    `Username_Clean`,
                    `Password`,
                    `Email`,
                    `ActivationToken`,
                    `LastActivationRequest`,
                    `LostPasswordRequest`, 
                    `Active`,
                    `Group_ID`,
                    `SignUpDate`,
                    `LastSignIn`
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    NULL,  // and that one
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->unclean_username)."',
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_username)."',
                    '".$secure_pass."',
                    '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_email)."',
                    '".$this->activation_token."',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0', // later, I would also try using an int for an int
                    '".$this->user_active."',
                    '1',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0'
                    )";
```

4) to find another one, better coded, using OOP and PDO.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I actually found some other called, a class called "access_user" which seems to be a whole lot better.  So far I have not had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You given Name as NOT NULL and in Insert statement of your code is not sending Name value, so mysql will throw an exception, saying Name cannot be null, check this once.

Comment: though Name is NOT NULL but it's absolutely okay for the INSERT statement to not contain it. MySQL will throw no errors, it will only insert an empty value into the `name` column. Had it been allowing NULLs, it would have stored NULL instead.

Comment: Ahum. The fact that MySQL will accept it (with a warning, mind) does not mean that it's a good plan, unless you've passed a default value for that column. Inserting an empty string just to bypass NOT NULL doesn't make sense at all.